# How do I setup Firebase auth to protect my .Net Core API

Tags: firebase-authentication, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to authenticate my back end API (which is currently only local) with Firebase auth according to [this blog](https://blog-bertrand-thomas.devpro.fr/2019/10/24/api-authentication-with-asp-net-core-3-0-and-firebase/).

I always get an 401 unauthorized even when I'm passing (I assume) the correct token. I just use the `[Authorize]` attribute on my controller.

Do I need more setup, allow localhost domain, setup permissions or did I do the setup wrong?

My Firebase console

[image]

My Startup.cs

```
     .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            string projectId = "eisenhower-255ca";
            options.Authority = "https://securetoken.google.com/" + projectId;
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = "https://securetoken.google.com/" + projectId,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = projectId,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
            };
        });
```

This is the JWT token I send

```
{
  "name": "My Name",
  "picture": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-5TcxgD5tEPM/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AAKWJJNudlhDY8TkE5x1HLlh7hwZFA5dew/photo.jpg",
  "iss": "https://securetoken.google.com/eisenhower-255ca",
  "aud": "eisenhower-255ca",
  "auth_time": 1588413429,
  "user_id": "3Ot95XQyenTvBmdTnGO5HcsihBs2",
  "sub": "3Ot95XQyenTvBmdTnGO5HcsihBs2",
  "iat": 1588413429,
  "exp": 1588417029,
  "email": "myEmail@gmail.com",
  "email_verified": true,
  "firebase": {
    "identities": {
      "google.com": [
        "110210403554430687155"
      ],
      "email": [
        "myEmail@gmail.com"
      ]
    },
    "sign_in_provider": "google.com"
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had middleware in the wrong order:

was

```
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAuthentication();
```

should be

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```